# Add days to a date and display it, excluding weekends & holidays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with manually added date and a drop down menu with some options. When user select option a, it should add specific number of days(i.e: 4 days) to the manually added start date, excluding weekends and holidays and display the new date in another div.

I am planning to use JQuery for this, I research about how to go about this, I found these two, JSfiddles, since I am very newbee in this I don't know where to start from this to achieve the result, I want. Here is the two mentioned JSfiddles. http://jsfiddle.net/r3RKq/4/ & http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/sZ5jq/24/

I have create the basic HTML structure for it:

```
<div class="start-date">26-04-2014</div>

<select id="uniform">
<option value='3'>Small</option>
<option value='2'>Medium</option>
<option value='1'>Large</option>
</select>

<!-- Small takes 4 days to finish
 Medium takes 6 days to finish
 Large takes 8 days to finish
-->

<button id="calculate">calculate</button>

<span>Estimated Possible Date:</span><div id="result" />
```

I would really appreciate any help to achieve this. I really need this. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: To make your job easier, I recommend taking a look at [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: @InternalFX Thank you for the link, but I am clueless how can I get start using it to solve this problem. Please if you any starting point, please enlighten me. I am really new to this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to solve this problem only on the client side, because there is no strict pattern of holidays, hence you need table of business days or holidays. If you works with foreign customers it becomes more complicated.

In our project we have classifier of holidays, storing in database. When i need to add business days, i asking server side to do id. Server using version of classifier, which depends of specifing customer and adjusting manually.

Comment: This is a small local intranet site, that actually have holidays defined. Please take a look at this JSFiddle where they have achieved holidays integrated to the JQuery http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/sZ5jq/24/ Please enlighten me, how I can go about and solve this problem. Your help very much appreciated. Thank you.